# Setting the previous image right before calling transitionWithView

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have a placeholder `UIImageView` (loaded from a .xib) which I want to load with a picture of the back of a card and then flip to the front image.

```
[cardView setImage:backCardImage];
[UIView transitionWithView:cardView 
                  duration:1        
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{         
                    [cardView setImage:frontCardImage];
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

The problem is that the initial image it starts with is not `backCardImage`, instead, it uses the no image (i.e. blank image) from my .xib file. If I had the backCardImage loaded in the .xib and only call `transitionWithView`, I believe it would work properly, but I would really like to have the two calls (`setImage`, and `transitionWithView`) in the same method. Is there any way to do this? Do I need to call something between the two?

I tried using `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardView won't draw, even if you put in setNeedsDisplay, until the next drawing cycle, so you need to set that image in another method first, or move the animation to another method, and call it with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:. Even a delay of 0 will work. I don't think the animation looks very good though, because you only see the back image for an instant before the flip (a delay of .1 or .2 seconds looks better I think). Why not set the back image earlier? What's the purpose of a placeholder image in this context?

Comment: thx man. you save my day and brain. where did you get this info that view won't draw ?